# How to create Rest API in Jetty 12 using Handler.Abstract

Tags: java, jetty, embedded-jetty, jetty-12

Jetty 12 Programmer Documentation has this:

```
class RESTHandler extends Handler.Abstract
{
    @Override
    public boolean handle(Request request, Response response, Callback callback)
    {
        // Implement the REST APIs, remembering to complete the callback.
        return true;
    }
}
```

I would like to know how to create a REST API in the above block.

I know using Jersey and Servlet Container it is possible to create. But not sure how to create REST API using Jetty Handlers alone.

The one option that is possible is to parse the request using request.getComponents() and tokenizing request params.

I was trying to use:
`request.getComponents()`
which would return like this:
`HttpChannelState@d735a98{handling=Thread[server-20,5,main], handled=false, send=SENDING, completed=false, request=GET@0 http://localhost:8080/shop/?id=122&city=new%20york&country=usa HTTP/1.1}`

Need help please.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The one option that is possible is to parse the request using request.getComponents() and tokenizing request params.

The `request.getComponents()` is for [Components](https://eclipse.dev/jetty/javadoc/jetty-12/org/eclipse/jetty/server/Components.html) that are shared across all handlers and requests on the same connection.  There is rarely a need to access or use this object, and it exists for integration into cloud providers.

The raw query is available in the `HttpURI` on the request.

```java
String rawQuery = request.getHttpURI().getQuery();
```

But then you would have to parse and url-decode that string yourself.

A convenience method is provided to do that for you.

```java
Fields query = Request.extractQueryParameters(request,
    StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

String member = query.getValue("Member");
```

This snippet is from the `form-post` examples found at

- https://github.com/jetty/jetty-examples/tree/12.0.x/embedded/form-post

See the documentation for other examples on how to read from the request, and write to the response.

- https://eclipse.dev/jetty/documentation/jetty-12/programming-guide/index.html#pg-server-http-handler-impl